# What type of glue sticks to tiles?

Tags: repair, walls, tools, kitchens, adhesive

I have some hooks that has a glued surfaced attached to it. They look like this,

[image: super hot melt adhesive hook]

*Image Courtesy:* [*www.dhgate.com*](http://www.dhgate.com/wholesale/hot+melt+adhesive+tape+coating+machine.html)

I bought a lot of them. Like 50-60. I used them almost everywhere. Mostly in kitchen. The problem is my kitchen wall is has tiles on it. Its full tiles. After using 2-1 weeks some of them has fallen off the wall. After that each day 1 or 2 hooks fall. Now I have only 2 hooks left there!

2-3 days ago, I bought Silicone Sealant to attach them again. The shopkeeper told its the strongest glue that sticks to glass or tiles. But some how they dont work on my hooks and tile.

Could you tell me what type of glue should I use to stick them on tiles wall?  I know the original glue comes with hooks sticks very well on wooden platform. But  here my platform is tiles.

Comment: Silicon sealant is for sealing, it isn't designed to use as glue.

Comment: I thought so. But in Internet I found they are the one of strongest glue.

Comment: @sharptooth could you tell me what type of glue should I use then? There are varieties of glues. I get confused.

Comment: You need a glue that explicitly claims adhesion to both tile and the plastic which your hooks are made of.

Comment: The hooks are made of hard plastic.

Comment: There's a gazillion of "hard plastics". What glues to HDPE may or may not glue to PVC.

Comment: Cyanoacrylates (barnacle glues) are generally pretty good for hard, clean, nonporous surfaces. The bond is not flexible, so it can be shock prone, but it's MUCH stronger than silicone based glues.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably due to impurities/dirt on the tiles - you really need to get them clean.

I used isopropyl alcohol on mine, and scrubbed them hard. As soon as they dried I applied an epoxy and the hooks are probably now attached to the tiles more strongly than the tiles are attached to the wall :-)

Comment: I didn't wash them by any alcohol or other cleaner. I just used my hand and water. Also the tiles are new. There are no oil stain on it like other old kitchen

Comment: Even new, they will have whatever coating came from the manufacturer. If you are wanting to hang heavy items you could look into abrading them slightly with a wire brush - but be aware this could break through the coating and cause them to discolour over time.

Comment: I am hanging common kitchen items, like chop board, knives, pizza cutter etc. They are not heavy at all/

Comment: As @Rory Alsop has said try cleaning with alcohol first and mount a new one I have done this with success on tile. If it falls off also, maybe you purchased a "bad batch" of hooks. Purchase one of a different brand and see if it sticks. Of course any of the ones that fell off won't restick.